# What did I miss in this MariaDB query? I'm getting now a SQL syntax error

Tags: sql, node.js, mariadb, sql-insert

Every time I get Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'by, user, reason, active) VALUES (5, 663403380223377400, 793061601288388600, 274'.

```js
          connection.query('INSERT INTO modlogs (logtypeid, textchannel, message, by, user, reason, active) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', [5, parseInt(message.channel.id), parseInt(message.id), parseInt(message.author.id), parseInt(mentionedMember.id), reason, 1], (error, results) => {
            if (error) console.log('MariaDB Error: ' + error)
          })
```

Did I miss something in the query?

MariaDB version: 10.1.47

Kind Regards,

Corné

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`by` is a reserved word [in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-B) and [in MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reserved-words/), so you need to quote it:

```
INSERT INTO modlogs (logtypeid, textchannel, message, `by`, `user`, reason, active) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

A better idea would be to use an identifier that does not conflict with a reserved word (or keyword). There are plenty of words in English, and just a few hundred are SQL keywords.

Note that I also quoted `user`: it is not a reserved word, but a language keyword, but it is still a good practice to quote it.

Answer (score 0):

`by` is an reserved word.

`Reserved words cannot be used as Identifiers, unless they are quoted.`

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reserved-words/

Answer (score 0):

"By" is a reserved word, so it must be quoted to be treated as a column name in your insert statement. Change it to `by` i.e. enclose it in backticks to get rid of the error.

That said, it is best to avoid using reserved words as table or column names.